# Error: failed to find frame for selector - Playwright 1.30.0

Tags: node.js, testing, automation, playwright, playwright-test

peeps!

I'm trying to iterate through table inside an iframe to get all the rows (tr) and then get the first cell (td) of each row. The problem is when running my script an error is displayed. It looks like as there aren't table rows.

I really need help, I've been trying a lot of things. I already verify the locators etc.

```
Error: locator.count: Error: failed to find frame for selector "iframe >> internal:control=enter-frame >> internal:testid=[data-testid="qa--table"s] >> tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)"

   at pages/RetrospectivesPage.js:20

  18 |
  19 |         const rows = await this.frameContent.getByTestId('qa--table').locator('tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)');
> 20 |         const countRows = await rows.count();
     |                                      ^
  21 |         console.log(countRows);
```

Oh the other hand, when adding the "waitFor()" method at the end of the locator **.locator('tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)').waitFor();** It's displayed in console:

```
Error: locator.waitFor: Error: strict mode violation: getByTestId('qa--table').locator('tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)') resolved to 2 elements:
    1) <tr class="css-1rn8q3f" data-testid="qa--row-642c457…>…</tr> aka getByTestId('qa--row-642c45715ab87a0a8c063c2a')
    2) <tr class="css-1rn8q3f" data-testid="qa--row-642c3d7…>…</tr> aka getByTestId('qa--row-642c3d785ab87a0a8c0639d4')

=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for frameLocator('iframe').getByTestId('qa--table').locator('tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)') to be visible
============================================================
```

HTML:

```
<iframe>
   <table data-testid="qa--table" class="css-42fjzi">
      <tbody data-testid="qa--body">
         <tr data-testid="qa--row-642c45715ab87a0a8c063c2a" class="css-1rn8q3f"></tr>
         <tr data-testid="qa--row-642c45715ab87a0a8c063c2a-tags" class="css-1rn8q3f"></tr>
         <tr data-testid="qa--row-642c3d785ab87a0a8c0639d4" class="css-1rn8q3f"></tr>
         <tr data-testid="qa--row-642c3d785ab87a0a8c0639d4-tags" class="css-1rn8q3f"></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</iframe>
```

Playwright snippet:

```
constructor(page) {

  this.page = page;
  this.frameContent = page.frameLocator('iframe');
}


async getTableRows() {
  
  const rows = await.this.frameContent.getByTestId('qa--table').locator('tbody > tr');
  const countRows = await rows.count();
  console.log(countRows);

  for (const row of countRows){
      
      const firstCell = await row.locator('td:first-child');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the site you're manipulating? It's difficult to help without a [mcve]. Thanks. `for (const row of countRows){` won't work since `countRows` is an integer. Try `rows.all()` if you plan to iterate them.

Comment: Sure thing!, It's an Atlassian add-on, so you need to log in to my instance. If there isn't any problem, you can share me your email address to invite you.